# Sending message to ZeroMQ from Rails 4

Tags: zeromq, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to send message to ZeroMQ from Rails 4 application.

I added `gem "zmq"` to my Gemfile, then I use this code in some method in my Application Controller.

```
context = ZMQ::Context.new(1)
```

Rails prints exception:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::ZMQ
```

If I add `require 'zmq'`to application_controller.rb Rails prints other message:

```
cannot load such file -- zmq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this error. Gem zmq (rb-zmq) doesn't work correctly with ZeroMQ 3.x.x, only with 2.x.x:

https://github.com/zeromq/rbzmq/issues/25